# Como agregar una referencia externa para usarla en un User Control 2.0 en Genexus 16?

Tags: genexus

Estoy realizando un user control 2.0 en Genexus 16 en el que necesito usar una referencia del siguiente tipo:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Si lo agrego en form.HeaderRawHTML funciona bien, pero quisiera saber si se puede agregar de alguna manera dentro del user control para que de esta forma toda la funcionalidad quede encapsulada en el UC.

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar, gracias por su apoyo.

Answer (score -1):

Se me ocurre que puedes utilizar alguna de estas alternativas:

1. hacer esa misma referencia que haces pero en vez de hacerla en el objeto que usa el UC, hacerla directamente en el HTML del UC (esta es un poco más "hacky")
2. usar [css font face](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp) y apuntar a una font que esté dentro de una [Base Style](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?40587,Base%20Style%20property%20%28User%20Control%20object%29)

Espero te sirva.

Comment: @Federico Ya realice la prueba agregando la referencia directamente en el UC, pero sucede que la referencia no se agrega en la sección head, y sucede que al entrar por primera vez a la pantalla no carga el css, tienes que hacer f5, por lo cual no es conveniente.